# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, xamlparseexception

I'm using WPF on C# as code bellow

```
<Window       
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:DVRClientInterface.Utility"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"     
    xmlns:wpftoolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"   
    xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:DVRClientInterface.CustomControls"    
    x:Class="DVRClientInterface.MainWindow"
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    WindowState = "Maximized"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"    
    StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" 
    KeyUp="Window_KeyUp" 
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"    
    Closing="Window_Closing" Loaded="Window_Loaded"
     >
    <!-- WindowState = "Maximized" -->
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources\main_background.png"/>
    </Window.Background>

    <Grid x:Name="MainWindowGrid">
     //My GUI Code here

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run the app, it will throw following exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'DVRClientInterface.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '5'.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Line 9 is `xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:DVRClientInterface.CustomControls"`.

But I don't know why, before that the XAML still work fine. I just edit the code in the C++ project, and after that it always throw that exception.

Many topics said that it was caused by the projects config, but I don't know where in my projects config raise this exception.

Someone can suggest me how to fix it?

UPDATE: The output debug as below

```
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\MysticClient.exe', No native symbols in symbol file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110_clr0400.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\51e2934144ba15628ba5a31be2dae7dc\mscorlib.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\MysticClient.exe', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\e40da7a49f8c3f0108e7c835b342f382\System.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\cd235caf797fb017f140016be88f33b7\WindowsBase.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\b52bc540630c3aa5de542c382af35c20\PresentationCore.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\97e6b67983d07a066b68b3ae8be2f53d\PresentationFramework.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\cc4d9093563dadee370788bbc3ecf4fb\System.Xaml.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DVRClientInterface.App.App'
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\28586400bcaf94c13a9fd0dff4a1e090\System.Configuration.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\9ba07396ae369d010c5c3927a82ef426\System.Xml.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'DVRClientInterface.App.InitializeComponent'
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\CPPWrapper.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\CPPWrapper.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\CPPWrapper.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\CPPWrapper.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\CPPWrapper.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\Common.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\DVRClientCore.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\ClientCommunication.dll', Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x7757b499 in MysticClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\CPPWrapper.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\DVRClientCore.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\ClientCommunication.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\SecurityLabCode\DVRClient\Bin\x86\Debug\Common.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'
'MysticClient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x00a7ab9c.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Exception at memory location 0x00a7cae4.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x74e8b9bc in MysticClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
'MysticClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'DVRClientInterface.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '9' and line position '5'.
The program '[5664] MysticClient.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[5664] MysticClient.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Many thanks!

T&T

Comment: you should check "xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:DVRClientInterface.Utility" and "xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:DVRClientInterface.CustomControls" , seems like another is ok.

Comment: I tried to remove CustomControls and other ones, but this exception still occur. Before that it still work fine :(

Comment: I have added the debug output in my post, can you read it for more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Problem solved! I'm using Ctrl + Alt + E to open Exception Window, and I checked all throw checkbox. So the debuger can stop at the exactly the error code.

Answer (score 44):

This is not a problem with XAML.  The error message is saying that it tried to create an instance of `DVRClientInterface.MainWindow` and your constructor threw an exception.

You will need to look at the "Inner Exception" property to determine the underlying cause.  It could be quite literally anything, but should provide direction.

[image: example of an inner exception shown in Visual Studio]

An example would be that if you are connecting to a database in the constructor for your window, and for some reason that database is unavailable, the inner exception may be a `TimeoutException` or a `SqlException` or any other exception thrown by your database code.

If you are throwing exceptions in static constructors, the exception could be generated from any class referenced by the `MainWindow`.  Class initializers are also run, if any `MainWindow` fields are calling a method which may throw.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I put the break point into DVRClientInterface.MainWindow() function, it's not even go to this break point, I think it crashed before this constructor called. How to get Inner Exception?

Comment: I have added the debug output in my post, can you read it for more information. Thank you!

Comment: How do you see this window?

Answer (score 8):

It took me ages to work this one out, so for the benefit of searchers:

I had a bizarre issue whereby the application worked in debug, but gave the `XamlParseException` once released.

After fixing the x86/x64 issue as detailed by Katjoek, the issue remained.

The issue was that a CEF tutorial said to bring down `System.Windows.Interactivity` from NuGet (even thought it's in the Extensions section of references in .NET) and bringing down from NuGet sets `specific version` to `true`.

Once deployed, a different version of `System.Windows.Interactivity` was being packed by a different application.

It's refusal to use a different version of the dll caused the whole application to crash with `XamlParseException`.

Answer (score 4):

I had this when build my application with "All cpu" target while it referenced a 3rd party x64-only (managed) dll.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** this is not the solution but it's a workaround for a problem that can cause the exception presented in the question.

I've solved changing from Release Configuration to Debug Configuration.

Comment: I run success at Debug but fail at Release too, and I use the Ctrl Alt E answer check all and find the place where the exception occur, then I know what's the problem, I use some file that exist in Debug Folder but not in Release Folder.

Comment: Changing the configuration is not a solution. It could give information about what is wrong or what is missing as @yuyangJian said

Answer (score 2):

I have a ToggleSwitch in my Xaml View Page:

```
        <StackPanel>
            <ToggleSwitch x:Name="myToggleStartButton" 
                          Header="START" CornerRadius ="20" 
                          OffContent="Show" OnContent="Hide"
                          Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonRevealStyle}" 
                          IsOn ="{x:Bind Path=XamlProductionViewModel.XamlIsMainOnOffChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          Height="80" Width="100" Margin="20, 5">
            </ToggleSwitch>
        </StackPanel>
```

Suddenly I got an Xaml parse error:

in the  partial class ProductionPage : global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page (ProductionPage.g.i.cs):

> ```
> Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
>   HResult=0x802B000A
>   Message=XAML parsing failed.
>   Source=WinRT.Runtime
>   StackTrace:
>    at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
> ```

Clicking on the 'copy details' in the exception window I can read stack informations, but it still don't gives me the real reason for the crash.

So the solution for me was to add this code to my View-Page code-behind (ProductionPage.xaml.cs)

```
  try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (XamlParseException parseException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ff")}]: {parseException.Message}");
            foreach (var key in parseException.Data.Keys)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{key.ToString()} : {parseException.Data[key]?.ToString()}");
            }
            throw;
        }
```

Now seeing the crash I press once on the F5 going further, and in the Immediate Window I can read this:

> ```
> RestrictedDescription : Cannot apply a Style with TargetType 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton' 
> to an object of type 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch'. [Line: 192 Position: 35]
> RestrictedErrorReference : 
> RestrictedCapabilitySid : 
> __RestrictedErrorObjectReference : WinRT.ExceptionHelpers+__RestrictedErrorObject
> __HasRestrictedLanguageErrorObject : False
> ```

So now I know that the Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonRevealStyle}" caused the error. This is how I handle with Xaml parse errors.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem, I had literally just forgot to fill in a parameter value in the XAML of the code.

For some reason though, the exception would send me to the CS of the WPF program rather than the XAML. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error appeared when I asigned to both dynamic created controls (combobox), same created control from other class.

```
//dynamic created controls
ComboBox combobox1 = ManagerControls.myCombobox1;
...some events

ComboBox combobox2 = ManagerControl.myComboBox2;
...some events
```

.

```
//method in constructor
public static void InitializeDynamicControls()
{
     ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
     cb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
     ...
     cb.Width = 100;
     cb.Text = "Select window";
        
     ManagerControls.myCombobox1 = cb;
     ManagerControls.myComboBox2 = cb; // <-- error here
}
```

Solution: create another `ComboBox cb2` and assign it to `ManagerControls.myComboBox2`.

I hope I helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

A simple re-boot (reboot) worked for me.  Not sure why.  I also did a clean and re-build but I'm fairly sure that it was the re-boot that did it.