# WPF XAML parse exception occurred

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having the following exception:
`'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll`
I looked for it and have found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188542/system-windows-markup-xamlparseexception-occurred-in-presentationframework-dll)

Apparently the `CTRL+ALT+E` method and checking all the exceptions didn't solve my problem - or I used it incorrectly. I checked all the exceptions and it lead me to the `InitializedComponent()` function of my MainWindow and that was it.
Any ideas? I'm sending all my `XAML` code: `MainWindow`

```
<Window x:Class="DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PongGame" Height="406" Width="717"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
    >
<Canvas Background="{StaticResource fieldBGSP}">
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Pad.Area.X}"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Pad.Area.Y}"
                   Width="{Binding Path=Pad.Area.Width}"
                   Height="{Binding Path=Pad.Area.Height}"
                   Fill="{StaticResource RectangleFill}"/>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Ball.Area.X}"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Ball.Area.Y}"
                   Width="{Binding Path=Ball.Area.Width}"
                   Height="{Binding Path=Ball.Area.Height}"
                   Fill="{StaticResource EllipseFill}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

and my `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RectangleFill" Color="#FF0F4228"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EllipseFill" Color="#FF207CBB"/>
          <ImageBrush x:Key="fieldBGMP" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/texturesExport/background.png"/>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="fieldBGSP" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/texturesExport/pong_ingameSP.png"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

### Edit

I get the error at the lone `>` sign just before `Canvas`. In the editor the background image shows up just fine. No clue what could cause the issue.

I updated my code with the `pack uri` method.

Comment: please provide us with the inner exception if exists, this could very helpful to solve the problem

Comment: try to remove the space from the end of the `Background` property like this `<Canvas Background="{StaticResource fieldBGSP}">`

Comment: I did remove them, no difference. I will update the post of course.
I'm currently checking inline how to get those inner exceptions but all I find is how to get them by code :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the images' build actions set to resource?
Also you may try using [pack uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) for image sources, in this case it would be
`pack://application:,,,/texturesExport/background.png`

Comment: I used `pack uri` like this:
`<ImageBrush x:Key="fieldBGMP" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/texturesExport/background.png"/>`
and unfortunately it doesn't work. Shall I use `Image` instead of `ImageBrush`?

EDIT:
the location of my images in the project are:

`C:\Users\agoston\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong\DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong\texturesExport`

Comment: No I don't think so. Could you try inlining the resource like this?
`<Canvas>
  <Canvas.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/texturesExport/background.png"/>
  </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>`

Comment: I tried and I get the same error. The location is pointed to that `ImageBrush` by the way.

Comment: Apparently I don't think the images build actions are resource. 
How to do it? I don't find it online.

Comment: I found it, but I can't edit the build actions for my images. I can though for my `.cs` files :/ any ideas?

Comment: Apparently including the image in the project did solve the build action issue and it solved my original issue, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have no code in the *.xaml.cs file, the issue probably has to do with properly evaluating the ImageSource properties.

Comment out both ImageBrushes and see if that causes the exceptions to disappear.

[Here's a solution for your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835477/not-able-to-reference-image-source-with-relative-path-in-xaml)

Comment: Thanks for the input.
Now that i removed my `ImageBrushes` and the `Background` property of the `Canvas` I get a `LoadFromContext error`. I used to be find by the way.
I do have code in my `MainWindow.cs` and my other classes but before adding the `ImageBrushes` they worked fine.
EDIT: by the way after that `error` I hist continue and it is fine. 
Checking what you linked....

Comment: Another update: I used `pack ui` and it unfortunately doesn't work. I can start, so no underlines or whatnots, but I get the same `exception`.
I have my images in the following folder by the way:
`C:\Users\agoston\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong\DPCKOU_prog3hf_pong\texturesExport`

Comment: Provide me with more code, as well as the entire exception stack (incl. inner exceptions etc)

Comment: I would rather add the whole pack if it is more convenient for you?
A small example program this is.
Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B33RFc9jZBV5R0d5alVOTVZoVWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it would be better if you posted a gist ( or a few) - or uploaded this to a github repository. I will not unzip anything onto my computer, no offense.

Comment: Fair enough. 
I'm messing around with BitBucket but not sure how to. trying that now...

Comment: it isn't done yet but I'm trying to set up the build actions for my `PNG` images. Apparently I have no `build actions` property for those.
Any ideas?

Comment: Done, I didn't set the image to resource. All the help appreciated.