# 'Access violation' error in WinUI 3 desktop app cannot be 'caught'?

Tags: c#, messaging, visual-studio-debugging, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I have a fairly complex WinUI 3 desktop app (v1.2, .NET 7, x64 in Debug mode) that keeps failing (after a specific sequence of events only) with a message from Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise in the `Output` window that says:

> The program '[28716] xxxxxxx.exe' has exited with code 3221225477
> (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

The app starts a secondary window on the UI thread with

```c#
    if (App.ShellPage.SettingsStatusWindow)
    {
        StatusWindow = new StatusWindow();                               // create new window
        StatusWindow.Activate();
    }
    else
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new CloseWindowMessage());   // close windows
    }
```

and `StatusWindow` is closed in the `CloseWindowMessage` handler like so

```c#
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<CloseWindowMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<TraceMessage>(this);
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Unregister<CloseWindowMessage>(this);
        Close();
    });
```

if a `CloseWindowMessage` is received or in the `StatusWindow_Closed` handler if the `Close` button on the the `StatusWindow` title bar is clicked.

```c#
    private void StatusWindow_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
    {
        Closed -= StatusWindow_Closed;
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.UnregisterAll(this);
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new WindowClosedMessage());
    }
```

The `WeakReferenceMessenger` class is from `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messenger`.

Although the message is in the `Output` window, it is not from any `Trace` or `Debug` code and does not seem to raise any catchable `Exception` as `App` startup includes:

```c#
UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.UnhandledException += Current_UnhandledException;
```

but no handler gets called.

My best guess is that somehow, a message is being sent to either a `Closing` `StatusWindow` after it has unregistered for messages, or a `Closed` `StatusWindow`. Curiously, closing a `StatusWindow` by sending a `CloseWindowMessage` will cause the violation within about a second whereas closing the `StatusWindow` once by clicking the `Close` button not only doesn't cause the error, but any new `StatusWindows` opened afterward never cause the error regardless of how they're closed. This makes me wonder if it's an initialization issue.

I've tried to isolate the problem by stripping out all the other logic and building a small app with just the window, but I can't seem to generate the `Access violation` error.

Any ideas on how I can get .NET to throw a catchable error to help troubleshoot? Alternatively, an suggestions on how I might isolate the offending message or object reference? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make it fail in Debug mode?  Well then set your debug settings as follows:
**1. Enable native code debugging** *checked*,  **2. Just my code:** *un-checked*.    **3. Enable .NET Framework source stepping:** *checked*  **4.* Access Violation** exception (under Exception Settings in  the "Win32 Exceptions" category) *checked*.  Debug like that and it should take you right to where the problem is occurring

Comment: Thanks VERY much. I forgot the mixed-mode debugging. The debugger now tells me _'Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD09273127 (Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll) in xxxxxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.'_ so it's a reference to a non-existent object. The stack is a lot more informative, too. I just have to sift through it.

Comment: What settings are needed for VS 2022?

Answer (score 0):

To debugging the Xaml code please surround your Initialize method in the code behind with a Try-Catch as I previously showed here:
[XAML-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74657879/7036047)